# Pulling more than one column in R command "pull"

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to pull more than one column when using the pull command in R? How? When I try adding a second column (X2), R thinks I'm adding a new argument. See below.

```
data %>% pull(., X1, X2)
```

Comment: You cannot `pull` two columns. Can you add an example and show what you want to do?

Comment: you can only `pull` a single column. `pull` is similar to `$`. Please look at `select`

Comment: you can use `select` instead: `mtcars %>% select(3:5) %>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: What do you want as output? A list or a data.frame with only these two columns?

Comment: I want a dataframe with only those two columns

Comment: `df %>% select(X1, X2)`

Answer (score 0):

Pull outputs vectors, use `select()` to keep working with `data.frame`:

```
data %>% select(X1, X2)
```

Or in base R syntax:

```
data[c("X1", "X2")]
```